# No "maj13" chords within leadsheets package

Tags: symbols, lyx, music, leadsheets

So I'm trying to finish my master's thesis with the leadsheets package. So far everything works fine, but I seem to not being able to get "major13" chords to display correctly as superscripted "maj13" as it is the case with "major7" and "major9". I tried to create a minimal example using the template with which I work.
I am - as you can probably see - not very familiar with LaTex or programming at all, but I hope that this is a minor problem to be quickly fixed, even by an unexperienced beginner. 
Thank you for your help!

```
%% LyX 2.3.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,ngerman,a4paper,titlepage,12pt,numbered]{PhDThesisLyX}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{leadsheets}
\useleadsheetslibraries{chords}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\chapter{minimal example}

\writechord{Fmaj7} - is what I want; \writechord{Cmaj13} - is what I get
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding the input style. You also have to modify the default output style.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{leadsheets}
\useleadsheetslibraries{chords}

\setchords{
  major=\textsuperscript{maj},
  minor=\textsuperscript{min},
}

\begin{document}

\writechord{Fma7} - is what I want; \writechord{Cma13} - is what I get

\writechord{Fmi7} - is what I want; \writechord{Cmi13} - is what I get

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I obviously have and now it works like a charm, thank you for your quick response!